# Elasticsearch not displaying all the versions which are having the same match

Tags: elasticsearch

```
body: {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [

          { "match": { "content": "build" } },

        ]
      }
    }
```

I have given the search in this manner and i'm getting displayed only the latest version in which that match is present and the others are not getting displayed, can anyone find me a solution

Comment: Of course, it displays only the last version of your document. What did you expect? What is your use-case?

Comment: {
  "name":"hello",
        "content":"You stupid can build run dam cab can offset grid columns in two ways: our responsive .offset- grid classes and our margin utilities. Grid classes are sized to match columns while margins are more useful for quick layouts where the width of the Move columns to the right using .offset-md-* classes. These classes increase the left margin of a column by * columns. For example, .offset-md-4 moves .col-md-4 over four columns.",
 }

Comment: now if i post it for multiple times in different versions I'm getting displayed only the latest version .Now can i specify a personal version in the document so that i can search using that version number and can I be able to see all the versions posted if i do in that manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, elasticsearch does not store previous versions of documents. The version number is just a mechanism for managing concurrency.
For example: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18825

Comment: Can I give a personal version number in the document so that when I search for them I can search them with their version number and also can i be able to see all those documents listed if I do in that manner.

Comment: The different versions would each need to have a different _id in order to store them individually, and so you'd need some other unique identifier to group the versions as a single 'document'.

Comment: Can u tell me a process on how to group the versions